# SSIS The connection is not found. The error is thrown by connections collection

Tags: ssis

I have created a SSIS package using visual studio 2015 and deployed it SQL 2008 R2 server. I have attached the config file to SQL job step that executes the package and deployed the config file to the location.

When I run the SQL job, I get the error

The connection "XXXXX\SQL2008R2.XXXX" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found

After getting this error i Checked the configurations tab in the job step and noticed that the connections weren't selected
see screenshot below[image]

I then checked the check boxes and reran the package to get the same error
I am not sure that I am missing. It looks like the package is not reading the config file correctly

Comment: Typically this error means the names of connection in the config file and those inside the package do not match. We are sure that, inside the package, the names of the connection manager objects are identical to those used in the configuration?

Comment: I dont see any difference

Comment: When you add configuration using package configuration menu, it takes into account the existing connection manager settings.

Comment: I have compared them and they are just the same. What I will like to bring to your notice is that I have developed a package using Visual Studio 2015 and deployed it in Sql Server 2008 R2 box

Comment: That certainly could be an issue.  You will want to match your Visual Studio version to your SQL SSIS version.  So we may not be able to use VS2015 to develop 2008 packages.    Why not install BIDS to develop your 2008 package?  Other than that, you may try changing the Solution Property **Target Server Version** to 2008 when developing the package in VS 2015. More information [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea9c0360-d4f4-480e-b022-52b9d9189c51/visual-studio-2015-ssis-development-backward-compatibility-can-we-develop-2008-2012-2014?forum=sqlintegrationservices).